# Find the shortest path connecting some (s,t) - a greedy (?) criterion to a multi-commodity flow problem

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, network-flow, approximation

At page 7 from [these slides](https://cs.gmu.edu/%7Elifei/teaching/cs684spring17/lec8.pdf) there is a Greedy algorithm I want to implement.

It says

> let $P_i$ be the shortest path (if one exists) that [...]
> connects some ($s_j$, $t_j$) pair that is not yet connected.

$(s_j,t_j)$ comes from a set of *commodities*.

Without getting into the theoretical implication of the whole algorithm, I only wonder how to implement such a statement.

It is stated to be greedy, hence it should have an easy implementation.

Is there a standard way to do that?

EDIT: Is there also any better reference than slides?

Comment: Slides seem intentionally vague. Check out for example [Fleischer (2000)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170808115410id_/http://www.research.ibm.com/people/l/lkf/papers/lpmulti.pdf) page 8. The weights of the graph are updated according only when they are used. It's a bit like approximate column generation.

Answer (score 2):

Only the outer algorithm is greedy, in the sense of removing the path links in each iteration and never looking back. Use any algorithm (like Dijkstra) to find a shortest path for each remaining $(s_j,t_j)$ in each iteration. As a possible speed-up, you can skip Dijkstra for all $j$ for which none of its shortest-path links have been removed because in that case the previously computed shortest path will still be shortest.

Comment: What about finding $P_i$. So far, I can only think of calculating all the possible shortest paths.

Comment: $P_i$ is not the shortest path between $(s_j,t_j)$. Rather $(s_j,t_j)$ is the couple connected by the shortest path $P_i$ in the graph. I can't figure out a better way to find this couple without computing all the paths per iteration.

Comment: I see. You are asking about a way to compute the minimum over $j$ of all shortest $s_j-t_j$ paths without explicitly recomputing them all. I amended my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know a better reference than the slides I shared??